# Объединение двух битовых переменных. Битовые маски

Tags: c++, c

Вопрос на тему битовых масок. С помощью какой операции можно соединить две битовые переменные в одну? Обратная операция делается через зануление и битового сдвига, а тут придумать не могу(

`a = 0101
b = 1010
с = a ? b = 0101 1010`

Answer (score 2):

```
с = (a << 4)|b
```

или

```
с = (a << 4) + b
```

или

```
с = a * 16 + b
```